# React - How to check which npm packages are not used on a project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, package, npm-install

I use CRA approach (create-react-app) using npm install installed different packages for my project, I don't use many of them but manually check which of these packages is not used on the project and then remove it will be a very difficult process, is there a way quickly check which packages are not used on my project and remove them?

Comment: I'm pretty sure all the packages that are installed are required by CRA. why would they be there if you didn't them?

Comment: Are you talking about the default setup or after ejecting? Everything it comes with is used somewhere, unless you've ejected and started deleting some of the stuff in /config and /scripts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check for any unused `dependency` or `devdependency` with depcheck package in any nodejs project. Use `npx` to use this package without installing it, run following command in terminal:

```
npx depcheck
```